# Name of book that includes giant space creatures, resembling manta rays, that eat solar fuel and kill stars

Tags: story-identification

My dad has been trying to figure out the name of this book for two years, and I want to help him.

As he described the book to me, the story revolves around a society of space creatures that resemble manta rays that flow through the galaxy, destroying it by effectively consuming stars in short time periods, leaving no energy for planets to sustain life.  Does anyone know the title?  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 9):

Baxter's Xeelee Sequence, specifically [*Ring*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_%28Baxter_novel%29).

The space creatures are called photino birds.

Comment: The Dad here,  This sounds really similar, but I read the book back in the late eighties.  There was a human who developed a new star drive and was able to travel vast distances .  As I remember it, when they discovered the creatures they could do nothing to stop them.  The universe essentially ended in the end of the book, when energy reached equilibrium throughout the universe.  As I recall it was a pretrty depressing read.

Comment: Baxter started writing the Xeelee Sequence in the late nineties, and the photino birds are an important feature oof that universe. Perhaps one of the short stories?

Comment: Perhaps "The Baryonic Lords" (Interzone, 1991), which ends, "The river of time flowed, unmarked, towards the endless seas of timelike infinity." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuum_Diagrams

Comment: Just checked out Ring.  You were spot on, that is the book.  Thank you very much for the help.  You guys are great!

Comment: @Zach - if this answered your question, could you please click on the gray checkmark below the vote buttons on the top left of this answer to mark it as solved? Thanks!